# Lazy bytestring insanity

Tags: haskell

I'm really struggling to square this circle.

getPostContent uses Wreq to download a blog post and return it.

```
getPostContent url = do
    let opts = defaults & W.checkStatus .~ (Just $ \_ _ _ -> Nothing)

    postResp <- getWith opts $ baseUrl ++ url
    if postResp ^. W.responseStatus . statusCode == 200
        -- then return $ LEnc.encodeUtf8 $ postResp ^. W.responseBody . _String      -- :: Prism T Text
        then return $ postResp ^. W.responseBody . _String
        else return "error downloading"
```

This is consumed by parseLBS

```
do
     page <- getPostContent r -- :: IO String
     let
     -- parseLBS :: Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString -> Text.XML.Document
     cursor = fromDocument $ parseLBS page
```

As I understand it, getPostContent is providing `Data.Text.Text`, whereas I need `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString` and I cannot work out how to convert them ( thought it should be [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.3/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8), see code snippet above, but it does not compile either).

```
   Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
                with actual type ‘T.Text’
    In the first argument of ‘parseLBS’, namely ‘page’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘parseLBS page’
```

Compilation message with encode uncommented

```
Couldn't match type ‘TL.Text’
               with ‘T.Text’
NB: ‘TL.Text’ is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy’
    ‘T.Text’ is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal’
Expected type: (TL.Text -> Const TL.Text TL.Text)
               -> Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
               -> Const TL.Text Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
  Actual type: (T.Text -> Const TL.Text T.Text)
               -> Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
               -> Const TL.Text Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘_String’
In the second argument of ‘(^.)’, namely ‘responseBody . _String’
```

Comment: It looks to me like `encodeUtf8` or similar should work. When you say it "does not compile", what does it fail with exactly?

Comment: added that compiler message now too

Comment: Right. So `encodeUtf8` wants a lazy `Text`, but you have a strict `Text`. I think there's a conversion function somewhere... Yeah, try `Data.Text.Lazy.toStrict` or `fromStrict`.

Comment: Yes! That fixed it. I think I thought that using the lazy library would ensure the conversion to lazy for me

Comment: Turned out that the use of _String was affecting things while being unneeded anyway and then everything joined up now easily anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise: `encodeUtf8` is the right way to go. It seems the one you're using is from `Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding`, which requires a lazy `Text`. You can use `Data.Text.Lazy.fromStrict` to convert... Or you can look into `Data.Text.Encoding`, which works on strict `Text` (but then gives you a strict `ByteString`...)